# Pandas dataframe count Strings and Postive numbers in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe, that has a column 'A1' that contains multiple 'Hello' strings, postive as well as negative integers. I want to count the 'Hello' strings, all number >= 0 and all numbers < 0, so that i get three sums in the end.

| index | A1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | Hello |
| 2 | -8 |
| 3 | Hello |

So the Output should be for posNums 1, negNums 1 and helloCount 2

```
posNums = df.where(df['A1'] >= 0).sum()
```

This doesnt work obviously, because one cant compare string to int. But how can I add here some condition that skips the str when I count ints and vice versa?

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use pd.to_numeric:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A1": ["Hello", 1, -1, "Hello", "Hello", -2, 2, -3]})

agg_funcs = {
    "negative": lambda x: x.lt(0).sum(),
    "positive": lambda x: x.ge(0).sum(),
    "nans":     lambda x: x.isna().sum()
}

out = pd.to_numeric(df["A1"], errors="coerce").agg(agg_funcs)
```

out:

```
negative    3
positive    2
nans        3
Name: A1, dtype: int64
```